# How could I routing to the app/webroot folder? (CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

If I type this: "http://examplepage.com/gallery/examplecagegory/1-test-picture.jpg" to the browser.

Go to webroot:
"app/webroot/gallery/pictures/1.jpg"

I tried:

```
Router::connect('/gallery/:slug_category/:id-:slug.:extension',
                array('webroot/gallery/pictures'),
                array(
                    'pass' => array('id', 'slug'),
                    'id' => '[0-9]+'
                    )
                );
```

But I stucked in the second row... :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not something you can do with routing, as [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) states:

> Routing is a feature that maps URLs to **controller actions**.

An image resource is not a controller action. You should just use a plain RewriteRule in the .htaccess file in `app/webroot` to rewrite all calls. Something like this should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/[a-z]+/([0-9]+)-[a-z-]+\.([a-z]{3})$ /gallery/pictures/$1.$2
```

Please do be aware that the HtmlHelper searches for images in the `app/webroot/images` folder by default, so you will need to use absolute URLs (prefix all image calls with a leading slash) to use your rewritten path, for example **this will not work**:

```
$this->Html->image('gallery/examplecategory/1-test-picture.jpg');
```

You should use this instead:

```
$this->Html->image('/gallery/examplecategory/1-test-picture.jpg');
```